# OOP в javascript

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть код:

```
var playername= "Test";
function Hatkutyun(life,speed,playername) {
    this.Life = life;
    this.Speed = speed;
    this.level = 1;
    this.playername = playername;
} 
var xaxacox1 = new Hatkutyun(3,10);
var xaxacox2 = new Hatkutyun(2,11);
var xaxacox3 = new Hatkutyun(4,7);
```

Хочу записать значение `playername`: `document.write(xaxacox1.this.playername);`, но не работает. Как исправить?

Comment: `var xaxacox1 = new Hatkutyun(3, 10, "myName"); document.write(xaxacox1.playername);`

Answer (score 1):

`this` внутри конструктора указывает на конструируемый объект, таким образом при обращении к уже готовому объекту его указывать не надо

```
document.write(xaxacox1.playername)
```

Кроме того, вы не передаете параметр *playername*, таким образом поле `playername` объектов `xaxacox1`,`xaxacox2`,`xaxacox3`- всегда будет *undefined*

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вы напрасно указываете **this** в этом коде:

```
xaxacox1.this.playername
```

В-вторых, вы при вызове конструктора не присваиваете поле playername, поскольку ни в одном из трех случаев не передаете этот параметр. Вероятно, вы думаете, что это поле инициализируется значением внешней переменной

```
var playername= "Test";
```

но это не так, поскольку внутри конструктора у вас есть параметр с таким же именем, и именно он присваивается полю, а не внешняя переменная

Answer (score 1):

Если цель - задать значение по умолчанию то:

```
function Hatkutyun(life,speed,playername) {
   playername = playername || 'Test';
   //или playername = (playername === undefined) ? "test" : playername;
   this.Life = life;
   this.Speed = speed;
   this.level = 1;
   this.playername = playername;
}
```

**Обновление**

Есть более универсальный но длинный вариант:

```
playername = (playername === undefined) ? "test" : playername;
```

Comment: Ваш подход работает не верно, если `plyaername = 0` или `plyaername = ''`.

Comment: Я знаю. Просто мне показалось, что на это стоит обратить внимание ТС)